# Angular http post request always sends an empty object

Tags: angular, http

I'm trying to POST some data using angular and I keep getting an empty object on the response when I inspect it with Postbin. I subscribe to this function elsewhere in my code so I'm sure the request is going through:

Everything works fine using Postman, but I can't see what is wrong with the code below:

```
postRequest(order): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const data = {
      "data": {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "John",
        "Class": "Adventurer",
        "Items": [
          "641",
          "642",
          "643",
          "513",
          "512"
        ]
      }
    }
    return this.http.post('https://requestb.in/wjoscywj', { body: JSON.stringify(data) }, { headers: headers })
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Comment: If you get an empty response it's an issue with the server, not with Angular.

Comment: Debugging the server, what does your server side code receive from angular and how is it processed? - `I subscribe to this function elsewhere in my code so I'm sure the request is going through` - Never assume, anything, always debug and make sure.

Comment: My server expects to receive a json object, but in the logs I get an empty object {}. I get a request object with an empty body, and my server returns a 422 error to angular.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer To make sure my server wasn't the issue I used request bin. Still getting an empty object there too. You can check the logs here: https://requestb.in/wjoscywj

Comment: If you are using chrome can you check your network tab (F12) and see the headers for what data you actually are sending.

Comment: Where *exactly* (code line) developer tools (plugin, ...) do you get an empty object?

Comment: I'm using an emulator unfortunately (cause ionic), I don't have access to chrome dev tools.

Comment: Don't `JSON.stringify` the body.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Just tried it, still getting the same issue. The requests are at 0 bytes on request bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tweak a few things:

```
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

to be on safe side.

You do want JSON.stringify. I normally do it without {body: } 
same for headers. 
so you have

```
this.http.post('https://requestb.in/wjoscywj', JSON.stringify(data), headers);
```

With the map you can just do

```
map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
```

Remember you have to subscribe to an Observable to start things going.

In your case I would tend to have the service with signature:

```
postRequest(order): Observable<Response> {
   //setup headers and do post here
}
```

That way you still have type safety at the method level.

Then, in the calling function do the map and subscribe like so:

```
this.postRequest(order)
  .map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
  .subscribe(data =>  { console.log(data);
                        this.data = data;
                      },
             error => { console.error(error)
                      },
             ()    => { // Finally
                      }
   )
```

Subscribe consists of 3 parts: Success, Error, Finally.
Error & Finally are optional.
If only 1 statement curly braces {} are optional.

Comment: This worked but I'm not sure why, I think I was adding the .map too early?

Comment: 1) You had not subscribed. 2) I see a lot of code out there with people coding what looks like a lodash map, rather than a Rxjs map... 3) I may be wrong about this, but it looks to me like your extractData and handleError, even if they did work, would not return a consistent type - one is json (success) that isn't an observable, the error is an Observable.. Also you have to bear in mind  when code is asynchronous.