# Can a Node / Express server accept all UTF - 8 characters safely?

Tags: node.js, angular, security, express, utf-8

Currently, I have a node server running express with a postgresql database. I know that postgresql supports UTF-8 encoding. My frontend is Angular and I believe that Angular takes care of any unsafe injection.

Can I get UTF-8 characters from Angular and run it through my node/express server and into my postgresql database without any security issues?

Are node/express servers vulnerable to injection?

If a malicious user manages to bypass Angular and access the API directly to insert unescaped input. If I send it back to Angular later, it should still be safe, correct?

Comment: angular has nothing to do with security. Everything in the frontend is 100% manipulatable by the user, it has nothing to do if they "bypasses" (as you call it) angular. As long as you are using prepared statements and don't insert user input directly, there shouldn't be a problem however

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* do security on backend, as everything front end can be manipulated by the user.

You can certainly get UTF-8 from Angular. Without proper handling, SQL I jections will be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 can be applied whenever you interact with HTTP... you just have to set it in the headers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213000/angular-http-post-request-always-sends-an-empty-object/45214168#45214168).

SQL injection is a result of not having things like prepared statements. It has to be done server-side, because a user could disable javascript in their client browser. For example [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Parameterized-queries-and-Prepared-Statements).