# Angular POST sends empty object in body

Tags: angular, express

I know this is a duplicate question to
[Angular http post request always sends an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213000/angular-http-post-request-always-sends-an-empty-object)

But I have already tried the answer and it does not work for me.

Here is my code:

Service:

```
registerUser(user: IUser) {
        console.log("Service 1");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this._http.post('/api/user', JSON.stringify(user), options)
                   .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                   .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error));
    }
```

Console Output:

```
Service 1
{"fname":"Abhisek","lname":"Mishra","email":"abhisek.mishra@gmail.com","pwd":"abhisek","dob":"1991-11-15","gender":"male"}
```

If I add a console in map, it inserts with no value and returns just _id and _v

Component:

```
registerUser(user: IUser):void {
        console.log("Component 1");
        console.log(user);
        this._userConnection.registerUser(user)
            .subscribe((usr) => {
                console.log("component 2");
                console.log(usr);
                this.statusMessage = "Added !!";
                },
                  (error) => {
                      console.log(error);
                      this.statusMessage = error.statusText;
                  })
    }
```

express '/api/user' works just fine. I tried with Postman. But when I try from application the console returns empty object

```
router.post('/user', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var usr = new user();
    usr.fname = req.body.fname;
    usr.lname = req.body.lname;
    usr.email = req.body.email;
    usr.pwd = req.body.pwd;
    usr.dob = req.body.dob;
    usr.gender = req.body.gender;

    usr.save(function(err, usrl){
        if(err) {
            res.send("Error! " + err);
        } else {
            res.json(usrl);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What returns empty? express req.body or client side subscribe?

Comment: express `req.body` returns empty object when tried through application. But when tried through Postman, it returns the correct object.

Comment: In .map mehthod of your service function, what is the value of response? Can you post the console.log(response)?

Comment: Please also console log the user value in service

Comment: Try changing 

`this._http.post('/api/user', JSON.stringify(user), options)` 

to 

`this._http.post('/api/user', user, options)`. 

(remove `JSON.stringify` method, just send user)

Helped me once.

Comment: Removed `JSON.stringify`, but still does not work

Comment: Heve you configured your express app to receive json? Are you sending json with postman? What does your browser dev tools panel say about your request: does it have the JSON body you expect? Why are you still using the Http service as it was supposed to be used in angular 2.0-beta, instead of using the HttpClient of the current angular version, as documented?

Comment: Stupid me !! I had used body-parser to parse URL encoded form data (which is why Postman worked) but I dint parse JSON. It is working now. Thanks :)